# Negation of "If P(n) is true for infinitely many n∈N, then P(n) cannot be false for infinitely many n∈N."

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've recently gotten to the ending of Chapter 2 of "Mathematical Proofs: A Transition to Advanced Mathematics", and was doing the supplemental exercises when I came across the following question:

"Let $P(n)$ be an open sentence over the domain $N$ of natural numbers. State the negation of each of the following statements:

a) If $P(n)$ is true for infinitely many $n \in N$, then $P(n)$ cannot be false for infinitely many $n \in N$."

Now, the answer key of the book says that the answer to this would be "If $P(n)$ is true for infinitely many $n \in N$, then $P(n)$ can be false for infinitely many $n \in N$."

However, I ended up with a different answer. Since $P \implies Q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg P \lor Q$, and the negation of $\neg P \lor Q$ is $P \land \neg Q$, I concluded that the negation of the statement in (a) could be written as "$P(n)$ is true for infinitely many $n \in N$, and $P(n)$ is false for infinitely many $n \in N$."

Is this a valid negation for the statement in (a)? I understand that the answer provided by the textbook could be correct, but I'm just curious whether my approach is right or not.

Comment: Rewrite the original as: if there are infinitely many for which P(n) is true, then there are infinitely many for which P(n) is not false.

Comment: No, the book's answer isn't correct. There's no way to rewrite the conditional that the book suggests into a conjunction, which the answer you got and the correct one.

Comment: By the way that statement isn't true. There are infinitely many even numbers but there are also infinitely many numbers that are not even.

Comment: I think the book answer would make sense if there was a quantification on all $P$, but not if $P$ is fixed

Comment: There isn't even really a clear way to interpret the statement that the book provides as an answer, for example the statement "The elements of $S\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ can be even" doesn't really mean anything, $S$ could still have only even elements or only odd elements, or some mixture

Comment: The wording of statement (a) is ambiguous, in my opinion. it is not clear if the "cannot" is negating just "$P(n)$ is false", or all of "for infinitely many $n, P(n)$ is false". Mauro ALLEGRANZA's comment interprets it as just negating "$P(n)$ is false", which makes (a) a trivial tautology, while John Douma's comment interprets it as negating "for infinitely many $n, P(n)$ is false", which as his example shows, means (a) is false. So to negate (a), you first have to decide which of these interpretations you are negating. But the book's answer doesn't make sense in either case.

Comment: Seconding @Paul's comment.